# Type mismatch error while using Generics in Kotlin List

Tags: generics, kotlin

Suppose say I have two model classes

```
open class Entity{

}

class EntityParcel : Entity(){

}
```

And a simple class with companion methods to convert a `List<Entity>` to `List<EntityParcel>`

```
class ConvertFactory{

    companion object{
        fun toParcel(e:Entity):EntityParcel{
            return EntityParcel()
        }

        fun toParcel(list:List<Entity>):List<EntityParcel>{
            val aList:ArrayList<EntityParcel> = ArrayList()
            list.forEach{
                aList.add(toParcel(it))
            }
            return aList
        }
    }

}
```

Now I'm trying to make use of the above classes and methods with generics like this

```
class CustomClass<E:Entity,P:EntityParcel>{

    fun someMethod(){
        val eList:List<E> = emptyList()

        val pList:List<P> = ConvertFactory.toParcel(eList)
    }

}
```

I get a compiler error `Type mismatch: inferred type is List<EntityParcel> but List<P> was expected` in the line

```
val pList:List<P> = ConvertFactory.toParcel(eList)
```

By defining `P:EntityParcel` in `CustomClass` and making `toParcel` method return immutable `List<EntityParcel>` I assumed such castings will be taken care of. But looks like I'm missing something here. Is there a proper way to do this? Help much appreciated.

Edit: Let's say the only purpose of the class `CustomClass` is to convert a given `List<Entity>` to `List<EntityParcel>`. Also, the class has to use Generics to achieve this conversion as I might use the same class to convert a list of `SomeOtherEntity` to a list of `SomeOtherEntityParcel`. This way I would only have to write what gets copied from an Entity to its Parcel and abstract all of the other conversion boilerplates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, if `P` is not `EntityParcel` but some subtype e.g. `Nothing` (which `P:EntityParcel` allows), then the type of `pList` is `List<Nothing>` and a `List<EntityParcel>` doesn't fit. "The proper way" strongly depends on what `CustomClass` is supposed to actually do.

> Also, the class has to use Generics to achieve this conversion as I might use the same class to convert a list of SomeOtherEntity to a list of SomeOtherEntityParcel. This way I would only have to write what gets copied from an Entity to its Parcel and abstract all of the other conversion boilerplates. (Also added this as an edit to the question)

Something like

```
abstract class CustomClass<E:Entity,P:EntityParcel>{

    fun eToP(entity: E): P

    fun listEToListP(list: List<E>): List<P> {
        val aList: ArrayList<E> = ArrayList()
        list.forEach {
            aList.add(toParcel(it))
        }
        return aList
    }
}
```

The thing is, you don't really need to implement conversion for lists if you have conversion for their elements, it's in the standard library as `map`:

```
fun listEToListP(list: List<E>): List<P> = list.map { eToP(it) }
```

Comment: Let's say the only purpose of the class CustomClass is to convert a given List<Entity> to List<EntityParcel>. Also, the class has to use Generics to achieve this conversion as I might use the same class to convert a list of SomeOtherEntity to a list of SomeOtherEntityParcel. This way I would only have to write what gets copied from an Entity to its Parcel and abstract all of the other conversion boilerplates. (Also added this as an edit to the question)

Comment: Perfect. Thank you. Solves my problem. Just to understand the error better, how can I not allow `P` to be anything other than `EntityParcel` like say `Nothing` for e.g.

Comment: If you want to not allow P to be anything other than EntityParcel, just remove `P` and use `EntityParcel` instead. The whole point of type parameters is to allow `P` to be something else, and the only constraint allowed in Kotlin is "any subtype of `EntityParcel` (or some other type) including `Nothing`".